# Bootstrap input tags overflowing panel body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following `panel` inside my project:

[image]

As you can see, there is something drastically wrong with it... i.e the `bootstrap` input tags decide to overflow and go outside of the `panel`.

My question is how can I get this to wrap onto the next line when there isn't enough space on the given line...

I have the following `html`:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
      <div style="max-width:100%">
         <span *ngFor="let hobbie of sport.hobbies" class="label label-success" style="padding:2%; margin-right:1%">{{hobbie.name}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried setting the `max-width`, `display:inline-block`, `word-wrap: break-word` yet none of these solution which I found on the web worked for me.

Can anyone suggest what else I could try?

Comment: Please add a working fiddle.

Comment: add code otherwise it is difficult to assume what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Panel is will already stay inherit to the parent. So you'll not need max-width set to 100%. But if you are trying to make sure that the buttons will cover all the row and start on new line if overflow. Either you can get rid of `max-width` or add code for column definition inside your `panel-body`, this comes from [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```
<div class=col-xs-12>
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you do it like so

```
  <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <span *ngFor="let hobbie of sport.hobbies" class="label label-success" style="padding:2%; margin-right:1%">{{hobbie.name}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the column grid of bootstrap and probably you won't need to apply any styles to it..

But it would be better if you provided a fiddle so we could be a better help to you!